# Interface to gDrive appears not to be supported yet using Google's Go language

Tags: google-drive-api

In the [SDK Example Apps](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/index) are listed examples for Java, Python, PHP, .NET, and Ruby, but not for Google's own Go. Doesn't Google promote Go as the up-and-coming alternative to these other languages? Don't get me wrong; I'm a big Google fan, but just curious why Go has been left out. Anybody know what's up with this?

Comment: Off topic… but a good point nonetheless. That *is* weird.

Answer (score 3):

Go supports Google Drive and a Go library is available in the project page:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/source/browse/#hg%2Fdrive%2Fv1

A complete tutorial is not available yet, it will be added to the docs soon.

Comment: Sure enough, there it is! Thanks, Claudio!